# How to insert images into a database using PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm wanting to allow a person to upload an image to the website that I'm making and I don't know how to do it. I know how to make the `HTML` form but after that, I don't have a clue. I have made the database and I'm wanting to do it in `PHP`.

Comment: I would store the image on my local system and write the path to it in your DB.

Comment: I agree with @chris85.  You definitely don't want people uploading stuff directly to your database.  You should be intercepting and checking the file.  Then, write the path to the database.

Comment: Surely you can get those fingers of yours to type in "how to store images in database php" via your favorite search engine ;-) Too many possible answers also.

Comment: storing images in a database is generally always a bad idea. whatever minor benefits you might find are invariably greatly outweighed by the pain it causes.

Comment: There are pros and cons to both ways. Using the filesystem as storage over the rdbms is the most common way and other use cases are rather niche, but they exist. examples: https://www.quora.com/Is-it-a-bad-design-to-store-images-as-blobs-in-a-database/answer/Bill-Karwin

Comment: You have a history of off-topic or heavily downvoted questions and are at risk of losing your question-asking privileges. You should [read this before you post your next one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254262/before-you-post-your-next-question).

Comment: One day we'll make a *system* for storing large numbers of arbitrary files. I propose we call it a *file-system*. Databases are for data, and when you start loading them down with huge binary files the consequences can be both predictable and unpredictable: Larger backup files, more filesystem overhead, higher CPU utilization, no CDN acceleration possible, etc.

Comment: Yet another whose button has been set to "ignore". Nice huh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally the best way to do this, is to upload the file to your server, and then store the path to it in the database.

File Upload: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

You need to choose a database, MySQL is a common and free option:

https://www.mysql.com/

As mentioned in comment below, (I haven't used it before but had a read and looks like a better option) https://mariadb.com/

PDO (recommended library to use with several types of databases): http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Note that there are many security considerations when letting people upload files to your server: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/32852/risks-of-a-php-image-upload-form/32853#32853

All in all, it may be longer than you think before your friend is uploading that file - but it will be worth it

Comment: Correct except use MariaDB instead of MySQL

Comment: @AdamJimenez hadn't seen this, looks good!